# Почему Хром и Яндекс(Браузер) по-разному отображают элемент?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Есть div с высотой 50px, ширина 100%. Проблема в том, что Яндекс(Браузер) показывает ширину 1300px с копейками(как и положено), а Хром 900. При этом визуально они одинакового размера, но если добавить к диву текст, то различия заметны(при размере текста в 10px эти же 10 в Яндексе меньше, чем в Хроме).

Comment: Вы знаете, у нас заведение высокой культуры. Немного поправил вам сообщения.

Comment: Ctrl-0 надо было нажать?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос закрыт, как оказалось это я сплоховал.

Хром поменял разрешение сайта без моего ведома и вот...